# Rotativa .cshtml file as Header and Footer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I have a PDF report from my ASP.NET MVC Project and I'm using Rotativa to generate the PDF, What I want to achieve is to have Header and Footer in my PDF using Header.cshtml and Footer.cshtml file (Razor file). because I need to display data from Database.

**You may download the complete project at this link** https://wetransfer.com/downloads/421708e46380e7ab4eb6f0de3c1a6cf620220303203032/7f0512

Error Message I received
[image]

In my Controller, I have this code to display my PDF report

```
using MyWebReport.Models;
using Rotativa;
using Rotativa.Options;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyWebReport.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Report()
        {
            var report = new List<ReportData>();
            var myreport = new MyReport();
            report.Add(new ReportData { Header = "This my Header", Footer = "This is footer", Body = "This is Body" });
            myreport.ReportDatas = report;
            string customSwitches = "--header-html  \"{0}\" " + Url.Action("Header", "Home", myreport, Request.Url.Scheme) +
                       "--footer-html \"{1}\" " + Url.Action("Footer", "Home", myreport, Request.Url.Scheme) +
                       "--footer-spacing \"10\" " +
                       "--footer-font-size \"10\" " +
                       "--header-font-size \"10\" ";

            return new PartialViewAsPdf(myreport)
            {
                PageMargins = new Margins(10, 10, 10, 10),
                PageOrientation = Orientation.Portrait,
                PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
                CustomSwitches = customSwitches
            };
        }

        public ActionResult Header()
        {
            var report = new List<ReportData>();
            var myreport = new MyReport();
            report.Add(new ReportData { Header = "This my Header", Footer = "This is footer", Body = "This is Body" });
            myreport.ReportDatas = report;
            return View(myreport);
        }

        public ActionResult Footer()
        {
            var report = new List<ReportData>();
            var myreport = new MyReport();
            report.Add(new ReportData { Header = "This my Header", Footer = "This is footer", Body = "This is Body" });
            myreport.ReportDatas = report;

            return View(myreport);
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyWebReport.Models
{
    public class MyReport
    {
        public List<ReportData> ReportDatas { get; set; }
    }
    public class ReportData
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Footer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Report View
**Report.cshtml**

```
@model MyWebReport.Models.MyReport

@{
    ViewData["Report"] = "View";
}
<html>
<body style="background-color:white">

    <div class="container" style="width: 800px; height: 500px">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold">
                @{
                    foreach (var item in Model.ReportDatas)
                    {
                        <tr style="line-height:10px">
                            <td style="text-align: center; width: 10%;"><p>@item.Body</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Footer.cshtml**

```
@model MyWebReport.Models.MyReport
<html>
<body style="background-color:white">

    <div class="container" style="width: 800px; height: 500px">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold">
                @{
                    foreach (var item in Model.ReportDatas)
                    {
                        <tr style="line-height:10px">
                            <td style="text-align: center; width: 10%;"><p>@item.Footer</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Header.cshtml**

```
@model MyWebReport.Models.MyReport
<html>
<body style="background-color:white">

    <div class="container" style="width: 800px; height: 500px">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold">
                @{
                    foreach (var item in Model.ReportDatas)
                    {
                        <tr style="line-height:10px">
                            <td style="text-align: center; width: 10%;"><p>@item.Header</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, post your code in a code sample (you could find some helpe here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), not as an image. Other people could help you faster and better if they could copy-paste to test and review your code.

Comment: Could you also provide the folder structure and file contect for your project (maybe and Solution Explorer overview image is enough)? Have you checked if the application works OK if you do nos set header and footer, or it remais displaying the same error?

Comment: Thank you Dave, Here's the source code, for you to check 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/421708e46380e7ab4eb6f0de3c1a6cf620220303203032/7f0512

Answer (score 0):

Apart form the error you are receiving, as well as you can notice in your code, you are trying to use an Razor view directly as HTML header, which won't work as you expect in the end, because the code inside the view won't be rendered. You should use an HTML file instead, or, if you want to post some database info (as you exposed), you might call the action to render the Razor view before it is displayed.

Modify the custom switches for Rotativa, using the code to call the action (supose it is called Header as you posted in your code, in Home controller), for example:

```
string customSwitches =
    "--header-html " + Url.Action("Header", "Home", myreport, Request.Url.Scheme) +
    " --footer-html " + Url.Action("Footer", "Home", myreport, Request.Url.Scheme) +
    " --footer-spacing 10" +
    " --footer-font-size 10" +
    " --header-font-size 10";
```

Remember that you are already passing the model to the Header and Footer actions on the previous sentence. Unless you have any special requirement, it should be enough to populate the model once, in your main action (Report, in this case). So your code for these actions could be as follows:

```
public ActionResult Header(MyReport myReport)
{
    return View(myReport);
}

public ActionResult Footer(MyReport myReport)
{ 
    return View(myReport);
}
```

Moreover, you do not need to use `\"{0}\"` and `\"{1}\"` in the custom switches (header and footer lines) or the escaped quotes (footer spacing and fonts lines), please remove them, and change the sentences to look like the code for custom switches suggested before, and be aware not to remove all the spaces between the commands (notice the space in the first character position of each string line in the sample code).

Even with these changes, your header and footer do not display anyway. This is because of the margins, check that if you remove the line `PageMargins = new Margins(20, 20, 20, 20),`, header and footer will appear on the page. Just try with other values in this options, and play also with footer spacing to get to the point that fullfills your needs. That should do the trick.

Comment: I try your suggestion and it works without error but the Header and Footer were not showing. The Footer of Shared Layout was shown into the Header part instead of the Header.cshtml

Here's the source code for you to check.
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/421708e46380e7ab4eb6f0de3c1a6cf620220303203032/7f0512

Comment: Hi @parpar, I edited the answer, please let me know if these changes solve the problem.

Comment: I tried an it does not work, I'm still receiving same error previously

Comment: Hi, @parpar. I've made a new update, this should work, as I tested it in your sample project. Please, let me know if this time it's ok.

Comment: Yup, it's work but I'm thinking why the menu was showing while were not using the _Shared Layout.  And also the Model value was throwing null values because the Data of passing to the page was null

Comment: If you wish to use no layout, you should add `Layout = null;` inside a code block (`@{  }`) at the top of your view, below the `@model` line. Which exact class/model property is storing null values? Please try to use breakpoint to check that the values you send in the model are persistent during all the process (when you populate them in the controller action, and even in the view, when the razor code is rendered).

Comment: Hi, @parpar. Any luck on this? Have you found new trouble?

Comment: Hi Dave Miller, Thanks for your suggestion but it seems doesn't work on my side after trying to implement the codes.

Comment: Hi, parpar. Can't check this deeply for a few days, but, please, update your post with the codes you are currently using, to review them. Have you also used a breakpoint to check the values as suggested? Please provide you current code and more concrete info about the errors you receive and the trouble you found, to help you properly. We can make this work, as I used it several times, just post some more info to evaluate correctly this problem and I'll answer you soon. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, parpar. Please, update the wetransfer link with you current project, and i'll try to check it. Thanks!